# More efficient way to compute mean for subset

Tags: r, dplyr

In this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  comp = c("pre",rep("story",4), rep("x",2), rep("story",3)),
  hbr = c(101:110)
)
```

let's say I need to compute the mean for `hbr` subsetted to the first stretch where `comp=="story"`, how would I do that more efficiently than this way, which seems bulky and longwinded and requires that I specify the `grp`I want to compute the mean for *manually*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
  mutate(grp = rleid(comp)) %>%
  summarise(M = mean(hbr[grp==2]))
      M
1 103.5
```

Comment: Do you want to get the mean for the 1st stretch of each subset or really only the for the stretch where `com =="story"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is any better, but at least you only need to specify that you want the first run of 'story':

```r
df %>%
  mutate(grp = ifelse(comp == 'story', rleid(comp), NA)) %>%
  filter(grp == min(grp, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(M = mean(hbr))
#>       M
#> 1 103.5
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can select the desired rows using `cumsum` and `diff`, and then choosing which group you need (here it's the first, so 1), and then compute the mean on those rows. With this option, you don't need to get the group you need manually and you don't require any additional packages.

```r
idx <- which(df$comp == "story")
first <- idx[cumsum(c(1, diff(idx) != 1)) == 1]
#[1] 2 3 4 5

mean(df$hbr[first])
#[1] 103.5
```